# Finding list containing unique elements in list of lists in python?

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list of lists like so:

```
list = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,3,2],[7,8,9,2],[5,6,8,9]]
```

I want to get the indices of the inner lists that contain unique elements. For the example above, the lists at index 2 is the only one that contains 7 and the list at index 3 is the only one that contains 6.

How would one go about implementing this in python?

Comment: I'd probably use Counter and sets for this task.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm not too sure what to try here. My first instinct is to loop through and store all the numbers I find in an array at the corresponding index, since they are all integers and then if I try to insert at an already full index again, I know I have a repeat. While I know how to do this, I don't know how this will return the indices for the lists I need.

Comment: if len(set(x)) <> len(x), then x has duplicate elements - with x being one element of list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using `Counter`. Each inner list is checked for a value that only has a single count, and then the corresponding index is printed (a la `enumerate`).

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(l))
idx = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if any(c[y] == 1 for y in x)] 

print(idx)
[0, 2, 3]
```

---

A possible optimisation might include precomputing unique elements in a set to replace the `any` call with a `set.intersection`.

```
c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(l))
u = {k for k in c if c[k] == 1}

idx = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if u.intersection(x)]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works well. I apologize if this is is a terrible question but could you point me to some resources or documentation where I could learn about expressions such as
idx = [i for i, x.....]

I've seen solutions of this form before but I can't wrap my head around what is going on here specially with the comma. Is it saying something similar to:

i,x = enumerate(l)
for k in i:
    ....

Or am I misunderstanding the expression.

Comment: @doddy The most obvious hit is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it ... for general tutorials, see here: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: Thank you. I apologize, I'm a beginner and really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> my_list = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,3,2],[7,8,9,2],[5,6,8,9]]
# find out the counts.
>>> counter = Counter(chain(*my_list))
# find the unique numbers
>>> uniques = [element for element,count in counter.items() if count==1]
# find the index of those unique numbers
>>> result = [indx for indx,elements in enumerate(my_list) for e in uniques if e in elements]
>>> result
[0, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `itertools.chain` with `set.difference(set)`

```
from itertools import chain
l = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,3,2],[7,8,9,2],[5,6,8,9]]
[i for i in range(len(l)) if set(l[i]).difference(set(chain(*[j for j in l if j!=l[i]])))]
#[0, 2, 3]
```